# Using com.jcraft.jsch to execute script on powershell not working properly

Tags: powershell, ssh, jsch

I can execute [powershell commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration) remotly using [com.jcraft.jsch](https://github.com/abij/ad-powershell-over-ssh/blob/master/src/main/java/nl/abij/service/PowershellSession.java) but when I try to call ps1 file which contains below code it does not work properly. Get-WindowsFeature return results but "ForEach-Object" or "Where-Object" do not return result and error.
Over console it works properly. The problem must be caused by "com.jcraft.jsch" but I could not resolve it.

[ssh over console works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLGz6.jpg)

[ps1 command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ux3EW.jpg)

[jsch result is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AA9Gq.jpg)

```
#test-1.ps1
Get-WindowsFeature | ForEach-Object {Write-Host $_.Name}

#test-2.ps1
$RequiredWindowsFeatures = @("Web-Asp-Net45", "NET-Framework-45-Features");
foreach ($RequireFeature in $RequiredWindowsFeatures) {
    $Feature = Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object { $PSItem.Name -like ($RequireFeature + "*") };
    if (-not ($Feature.Installed -eq $true)) {
        [console]::WriteLine("");
        #return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the error message (in full).

Comment: I add images, as you can see over jsch result is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
```

After I close progess bar of powershell, it works fine.